# App Crashes on AppDelegate Class Declaration with EXC_BAD_ACCESS CODE 1 on iOS 9.1/9.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, appdelegate

I installed XCode 7.1 and 7.2 to update my app for iOS 9.1 and 9.2 respectively, but each time I run the app on simulators or devices the app crashes on the AppDelegate's class declaration as shown below. However, I have also XCode 7.0 and when I run my app on iOS 9.0 it works fine without any issue !.

The problem even if I compile the app for iOS 9.0 it would crashes on any device running iOS 9.1 or 9.2, I tried to change the initial view controller to be a simple plain one but it seems that it never reaches the point of loading view controllers and never reaches the beginning of `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool`.

It seems that Apple did something with iOS 9.1 & 9.2. The app is written in swift, I enabled NSZombie and breakpoints to catch exceptions but I get no clue from the logs.

Debug Navigator:-

[image]

AppDelegate Class Declaration

[image]

Comment: You should be able to find out the crash point by setting up couple of breakpoints. Are you 100% sure that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions was not fired?

Comment: Have you tried to 1, clean and rebuild, 2, clean build folder and rebuild, 3, remove the application from the simulator and run it again?

Comment: @ViktorKucera  Yes I'm sure, because I wrote a print function as the first statement to be executed once the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions fires, but the log shows nothing. The only thing that gets printed is at the init() - which I do nothing at except calling super.init() for testing this problem - no other events such as "applicationDidBecomeActive", "applicationDidEnterBackground" or "applicationWillResignActive" gets fired before the app crashes.

Comment: @RashwanL Yes I did all that, and every time it crashes, the something happens when I run it on the device. Again, the only exception that this is working fine without any problem is if I run it on a device or a simulator with iOS 9.0 or below.

Comment: @MarwanJ are you able to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

That happens to me almost every time in new versions of Xcode/Swift/iOS. When I have had this problem I have erased that line and written it again.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

Comment: I did that and I double checked the iOS documentation and unfortunately I  found nothing wrong with didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have not set you variable types correctly. Check how you declare them. In my case i was trying to access a Bool as UIColor.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally had this happen when there is a storyboard problem. For example, an error in:

```
storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "FooView")
```

Try putting breakpoints around controllers that are being loaded around where you are crashing to see if that's the problem.